# When does the intersection of cylinders produce a ball?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Suppose one intersects unit-radius solid cylinders
in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with each cylinder axis passing through
the origin. For example, two such cylinders produce
the [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html).

But if we imagine starting with one cylinder with
axis aligned along the $x$-axis, and spin that axis
about $z$, obtaining an infinite number of cylinders
all of whose axes lie in the $xy$-plane, the resulting
intersection is a unit-radius ball:

---

[image: Cylinders3]

---

If we set a unit direction vector $u$ along each cylinder axis,
the spinning walks the $u$ vector tips around a great circle
on the sphere $S$ of directions.

Now imagine an arbitrary closed curve $C$ on $S$.
Form the intersection $I(C)$ of the cylinders determined by
all the direction vectors lying on $C$.
Again all cylinders have unit radius, and all axes are through the origin.
My question is:

> **Q**. For which $C$ will $I(C)$ be the unit-radius ball?

This might be straightforward, but I am not seeing it...

An analogous question can be posed in $\mathbb{R}^d$,
with each cylinder a line cross a $({d{-}1})$-ball.

Comment: As far as I can see, a necessary and sufficient condition is that $C$ should intersect each great circle. That is, a cylinder with axis $u$ excludes the points just outside the unit ball in the direction of the unit vector $v$ iff $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Nice, Andreas! And I think that generalizes to higher $d$. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it. Or just leave it as a comment, if you prefer.

Comment: In particular, $C$ cannot be strictly contained in any hemisphere $H$, for then it would not intersect the great circle determining $H$. Perhaps that is a more geometric formulation of your condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the OP's suggestion, I'm promoting my comment to an answer.

A necessary and sufficient condition is that $C$ should intersect each great circle. That is, a cylinder with axis $u$ excludes the points just outside the unit ball in the direction of the unit vector $v$ iff $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular.